# models not loading on phalcon multi module

Tags: php, module, phalcon

I'm trying to implement phalcon multi module with namespace.  normally its working. but models not loading from its location(/apps/models/). if I paste all of my models file into controller dir then its working. It should load from models dir. how could i solve this problem.

[Front Module]

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
array(
'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers' => '../apps/frontend/controllers/',
'Multiple\Frontend\Models'      => '../apps/frontend/models/',
 ));
```

[Blogs Model]

```
namespace Multiple\Frontend\Controllers;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
class Blogs extends Model{}
```

i also try "namespace Multiple\Frontend\Models;" but not success.
getting error like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\News' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pm\apps\frontend\controllers\IndexController.php:38 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
```

i have my dispatcher like:

```
public function registerServices(DiInterface $di)
{
    # Registering a dispatcher
    $di->set('dispatcher', function () {
        $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("Multiple\Frontend\Controllers");
        return $dispatcher;
});
```

i think the error : "Error: Class 'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\Blogs' not found" for this cause default namespace is frontend\controller. how to solve it? please

Comment: Why your Blog model is namespaced as Controller? Whats up with News in your error, its nowhere in your code sample?

Comment: What namespace should i use in blog model?  is it "namespace Multiple\Frontend\Models"? if yes then it show fatal error news model is in models directory thats why this error. if i copy news model to controller dir it work perfect

Comment: i want to call news model from models directory.

Comment: Did you forget to change the namespace in your `news` model to `Multiple\Frontend\Models`?

Comment: Timothy! If i change Multiple\Frontend\Models then i got Fatal error like: Error: Class 'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\News' not found. its only work if i paste all models into my controller dir

Comment: Can you confirm that **every single one of your models** has the namespace `Multiple\Frontend\Models`. Can you **triple** check this please?

Comment: Yes! Timothy. 100% Confirm

Comment: is this lines causing any problem:     public function registerServices(DiInterface $di)
    {
        $di->set('dispatcher', function () {
            $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("Multiple\Frontend\Controllers");
            return $dispatcher;
        }); please?

Comment: No, that line tells your dispatcher where it must start looking for a matching controller.

Comment: i'm just following multi module from https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple. just trying to use model. i didn't change anything from the example. i cant find out my wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add one extra line in your controller like...

```
namespace Multiple\Frontend\Controllers;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

use Multiple\Frontend\Models\Blogs as Blogs; //** This line should Add **//

class IndexController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{}
}
```

Comment: Gr8 Boss! its working... But i have a question that if i use multi module then every controller i should add models is that?

Comment: i don't know but i just solved my problem like this. ask some one more expert then me like Timothy. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

You need to load your models obviously outside of modules. The registerNamespaces is only hit in this module when this module is hitted by dispatcher.

Actually i thought that you have problems with using models in different modules. If you have this error `Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\News` that this can't be found it means that you just don't have proper use statement and it's looking for class in same namespaces, just add `use Multiple\Frontend\Models\News`. Are you even using any IDE ?

Comment: What you mean no working ? Just use loader and load your model classes before registering modules, here example - http://pastebin.com/CgzT7mGc

And then just `use Multiple\Frontend\Models\Blogs` or whatever.

It has to work, im doing the same in my application.

**As i already wrote, registerNamespaces is only hit when the dispatcher hit a module(like route) - this is why example works without any problem. If you want to use your models in multiple modules - you need to register them with loader outside of module class.**

Comment: @Juri, he uses Sublime Text, so no IDE :)

Comment: So i updated my answer. It's definitely beacause he doesn't have use i think.

Comment: Juri! Timothy is right i use sublime text.  and look my code on top i already do that after register namespace for controller and model both after application $di. Im asking why i need every time to add models in my controller?

Comment: What you mean to add models in your controllers ? This is how php works. You need to use `use class` if it's in another namespace.

Comment: Thanx! Juri 4 explain. but its like same to copy models in controller dir or tell controller where is the models dir

Comment: No, you just need to tell controller from which namespaces got your model :) If you would have no namespaces then this would already work. If model is in `Multiple\Frontend\Models` and controller in `Multiple\Frontend\Controllers` to use models in controller you need to use full namespaces like `\Multiple\Frontend\Models\News` or put `use Multiple\Frontend\Models\News` and then you can use just News anywhere.